# Eclipse: jsp, Syntax error on token , delete this token

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

Hi I have a Maven project. I am working with Eclipse STS. I am getting an error on a jsp file.

> Syntax error on token "<", delete this token   (line 22)
>
> Multiple annotations found at this line:       (line 27)
>       - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Arguments
>       - Syntax error, insert ") BlockStatement" to complete 
>        IfStatement
>       - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

Below is my code for jsp file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" 
prefix="security"%>

<security:authentication var="principal" property="principal" />
<script type="text/javascript">

var chooseSuperSellerPlaceholder = '<fmt:message 
key="global.chooseSuperSeller" />';
var chooseSellerPlaceholder = '<fmt:message key="global.chooseSeller" />';
var chooseCustomerPlaceholder = '<fmt:message key="global.chooseCustomer" 
/>';


var thisNotify;
$(function(){
initDate();
loadNotifications();
initDigitalClock();
<security:authorize access="hasAuthority('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')">
    initCombobox('#h-s-seller', 'SUPER_SELLER');
    initCombobox('#h-seller', 'SELLER');
    initCombobox('#h-customer', 'END_CUSTOMER');
    loadChildren('#h-s-seller', 'SUPER_SELLER', -1);
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.SELECTED_CUSTOMER != null}">
        loadChildren('#h-s-seller', 'SUPER_SELLER', ${sessionScope.SELECTED_CUSTOMER.parent.parent.parent.id});
        loadChildren('#h-seller', 'SELLER', ${sessionScope.SELECTED_CUSTOMER.parent.parent.id});
        loadChildren('#h-customer', 'END_CUSTOMER', ${sessionScope.SELECTED_CUSTOMER.parent.id});
    </c:if>
</security:authorize>
<security:authorize access="hasAuthority('ROLE_SUPER_SELLER')">
    initCombobox('#h-seller', 'SELLER');
    initCombobox('#h-customer', 'END_CUSTOMER');
    loadChildren('#h-seller', 'SELLER', ${principal.user.customer.id});
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.SELECTED_CUSTOMER != null}">
        loadChildren('#h-seller', 'SELLER', ${sessionScope.SELECTED_CUSTOMER.parent.parent.id});
        loadChildren('#h-customer', 'END_CUSTOMER', ${sessionScope.SELECTED_CUSTOMER.parent.id});
    </c:if>
</security:authorize>
<security:authorize access="hasAuthority('ROLE_SELLER')">
    initCombobox('#h-customer', 'END_CUSTOMER');
    loadChildren('#h-customer', 'END_CUSTOMER', ${principal.user.customer.id});
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.SELECTED_CUSTOMER != null}">
        loadChildren('#h-customer', 'END_CUSTOMER', ${sessionScope.SELECTED_CUSTOMER.parent.id});
    </c:if>
</security:authorize>
```

});

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse is confused by the mix of server-side jsp tags and client-side JS. Don't trust it. Test if your JSP works as it should, by deploying it and executing it.

Comment: I tested it but it doesn't work. How can I resolve these confuse?

Comment: Forget about Eclipse. Fix the code based on the error you get from your attempt to execute it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it.